# How to pass an array of C_FLOAT to a Fortran subroutine

Tags: c, fortran, parameter-passing, fortran-iso-c-binding

In Fortran I have an array of `C_FLOAT`, which is declared as an input argument:

```
SUBROUTINE Main(n,myCArray)  BIND(C, NAME = 'Main')
INTEGER(C_INT),         INTENT(IN   ) :: n
REAL(C_FLOAT),          INTENT(INOUT), dimension(n) :: myCArray
    CALL PrintTheArray(n,myCArray)
END SUBROUTINE MAIN
```

As written in the `Main` subroutine body, I want to pass `myCArray` to another subroutine as follows:

```
SUBROUTINE PrintTheArray(n,theCArray)
INTEGER(C_INT),         INTENT(IN   ) :: n
REAL(C_FLOAT),          INTENT(INOUT), dimension(n) :: theCArray
print *, theCArray(1), theCArray(2)
END SUBROUTINE PrintTheArray
```

By doing this, I never print the correct values of the array. However, if I print the values in the subroutine `Main()`, the values are correct. What is wrong and how can I fix this?

---

There is indeed no problem with passing a `C_FLOAT` array within Fortran. So the question is wrong. I provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here(I use Ubuntu, GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.3.0, gcc (GCC) 6.3.0):

Fortran code with file name `FORTRANFunc.f90`

```
MODULE TEST
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_Binding
  IMPLICIT NONE
contains
subroutine CALLFORTRAN(n,myArray) BIND (C, NAME = 'CALLFORTRAN')
  INTEGER(C_INT),  INTENT(IN   )  :: n
  REAL(C_FLOAT),   INTENT(IN   )  :: myArray(n)
  CALL PRINTARRAY(n,myArray)
end subroutine CALLFORTRAN

subroutine PRINTARRAY(n, myArray)
  INTEGER(C_INT),  INTENT(IN   )  :: n
  REAL(C_FLOAT),   INTENT(IN   )  :: myArray(n)
  print *, myArray(1), myArray(2)
end subroutine PRINTARRAY
END MODULE TEST
```

C code with file name `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern void CALLFORTRAN(int* n, float* myArray);

int main()
{
   int n=2;
   float*  myArray = (float*) malloc(2);
   myArray[0] = 0.5;
   myArray[1] = 1.5;
   CALLFORTRAN(&n,myArray);
   return 0;
}
```

you may compile with:

```
gfortran -c FORTRANFunc.f90
gfortran main.c FORTRANFunc.o -o test
```

then you execute with:

```
./test
```

The result should be:

```
  0.500000000       1.50000000
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] for us?

Comment: Indeed, what does it print then, when it does not print the correct values?  Do you have the correct values inside `Main()` at all? A detailed problem statement and a [mcve] is necessary.

Comment: I have a feeling the problem lies in the C code. Ordinarily, there is no problem passing arrays of C_FLOAT between Fortran subroutines.

Comment: The second line is usually USE ISO_C_BINDING. Is the C passing by reference or value?

Comment: @Holmz There is absolutely no reason for `use iso_c_binding` if it is already used i some module above. `use iso_c_binding` does NOT change the calling convention (pass by value/reference) in any way.

Comment: Why is the answer part of the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem with gfortran 5.4.0 (full version: `GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/IBM 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`) or IBM XL Fortran.  Could it be an issue with the newer gfortran?

```
$ gfortran -c FORTRANFunc.f90
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gfortran FORTRANFunc.o main.o -o test
$ ./test
  0.500000000       1.50000000
$
```

Also, does changing `dimension(n)` into `dimension(*)` make any difference?

Comment: Actually, the question was wrong, as clarified above. So it's totally okay to pass C_FLOAT arrays in FORTRAN. Changing {dimension(n)} to {dimension(*)} is also right.